# cmake: add linker/archive options before and after specific target

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linkage

I have a library which symbols should be imported to an app despite the fact they aren't used explicitly there. The purpose of the library is to execute static constructors and thus make itself available to an app at runtime (register its symbols).

I've found the corresponding flags (gcc): `-Wl,--no-as-needed` for shared library and `--whole-archive` for static. In cmake I can set a variable `LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE` to control `--no-as-needed` flag and `STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS` but they will be applied to all libraries listed next after. What I need is to apply them only for one specific library, i.e. `-Wl,--no-as-needed -lmylib -Wl,--as-needed` and `-Wl,--whole-archive -lmylib -Wl,--no-whole-archive`.

How to do this with the help of cmake in a cross-platform way?

UPD. I've found a way to do this but it doesn't look "cross-platform" enough:

```
target_link_libraries(
  myapp PRIVATE
  "-Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--whole-archive" mylib "-Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

It works on linux(ld) but I doubt it will be on windows/mac. Is there a way to do the same without hard-coded strings using cmake functions/variables?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. I already tried the same atempt as you suggested but couldn't get it running.

I have the following setup:
```CMAKE:
target_link_libraries(myapp -Wl,--no-as-needed mylib1 -Wl--as-needed mylib2)
```

When I check the dynamic sections of the ELF, symbols of `mylib1` are imported, but so are the symbols for `mylib2`

Comment: Hi, @moatze. Forget the comma after the second flag Wl, `-Wl,--as-needed`, didn't you?

Comment: sry my mistake. I put the comma, `CMAKE: target_link_libraries(myapp -Wl,--no-as-needed mylib1 -Wl,--as-needed mylib2)` the problem exists anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do the same without hard-coded strings using cmake functions/variables?

As of now, no there is not. You have to write `-Wl,--whole-archive` yourself.

I believe it would be nice to have some `set_target_properties(static_target PROPERTIES WHOLE_ARCHIVE true)` in cmake, but I also guess that implementation might be hard.

If you want to be cross-platform, you would detect it:

```
check_c_compiler_flag('-Wl,--whole-archive' has_whole_archive)
if (has_whole_archive)
    use_it(-Wl,--whole-archive)
endif()
```